# What is the difference between valorization and commercialization of education?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between valorization and commercialization? And what do precisely each of these words mean, when applied to education?

> *valorize* to enhance or try to enhance the price, value, or status of by organized and usually governmental action [[MW](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valorize)]

> *commercialize* to use (something) as an opportunity to earn money [[MW](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commercialize)]

To me, the meaning of *valorization* seems to rather be more accurate of how we use the word *commercialization.* At the same time, different dictionaries present differing definitions and then there are even more different definitions for these words as terms.

That's the reason why I am asking here, hoping that someone familiar with these terms could explain them. What does it mean to ***commercialize education*** and what does it mean to ***valorize education***?

Comment: I'm sure you've already looked in a dictionary or two. Please show what you found and what is still unclear, so that others may give a helpful answer rather than simply repeat what you already know.

Comment: I did not understand the meaning presented in the dictionary. The meaning of both words seemed contrary to colloquial use. I would appreciate if someone could explain these words as if they would use them in every day context.

Comment: So please **show your research.** Show what the dictionary said, and explain what you did not understand.

Comment: The dictionary presents the meaning of:
Valorization - to enhance or try to enhance the price, value, or status of by organized and usually governmental action
Commercialization - to use (something) as an opportunity to earn money

To me the meaning of Valorization seems to rather be more accurate of how we use the word commercialization. At the same time different dictionaries present differing definitions and then there are even more different definitions for these words as terms.

Comment: That's is the reason why i am asking here, hoping that someone familiar with these terms could explain them. 
What does it mean to commercialize education and what does it mean to valorize education?

Comment: To make it simple, the "commercialization" is done by the teaching organization to propose its services on the market and get more paying students. From the school/university point of view, "valorizing" is setting the prices of the course. From the student point of view, "valorizing" is to make the best from what he learnt.

Answer (score 2):

*[Valorize](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20valorize)* means to ascribe value to something.  In its general use, it means validate.  From *[Gender and Citizenship](https://books.google.com/books?id=u_FD3xl8zhcC&pg=PA81&dq=%22valorize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRtY7YqsPJAhXKcT4KHa6kAosQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22valorize%22&f=false)* by Claudia Moscovic

> While the narrator appears to **valorize** feminine ethics, Raymon
>   dismisses it as charming and infantile in order to validate his own
>   political views.

As a term of art in economics it means to artificially set the price of a commodity.  Consider this from a Depression-era monograph, *[Consequences of price fixing in competitive industries: with special reference to the proposed fixed minimum prices of petroleum products](https://books.google.com/books?id=gqovAAAAYAAJ&q=%22valorize%22&dq=%22valorize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitzs2JqcPJAhUFbD4KHSfSAT0Q6AEINjAF)*:

> The work of our Federal Farm Board tends to **valorize** the price of wheat and cotton.

*Commercialize* means to turn something into a business or manage something so as to make a profit.  It can have the connotation of exploitation or the subordination of virtue to moneymaking.  In its neutral sense, see the exhortations on the internet about **commercializing** your inventions.  In its other sense, see the seasonal moaning about the **commercialization** of Christmas.

To determine what these words mean with respect to education will require the context of their use.